# How to delete shortcut in notification bar (metacity)

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, metacity

I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS with metacity window manager and by mistake I created a link to my home folder just on top in the notification bar. I would like to delete it but do not know why.

[image: Folder in notification bar]

Comment: Have you remove folder shortcut yet ?

Comment: Yep your solution worked, hence the up vote

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted by clicking "check" symbol near the answer

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then right click on top panel, this function should let you edit items on top panel.